# Unable to get desired records using references in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need all blog posts based on category name.

I have a `posts` and `categories` collection.

Inserting into `posts` collection:

data:

```
{
   "title": "Test",
   "description": "description",
   "categoryId": "641c491e1707a9395caccd00"
}
```

Method:

```
async addPost(createPostDTO: CreatePostDTO) {
    const inserted = await this.blogCollection.insertOne(createPostDTO, {});
    const post = await this.blogCollection.findOne({ _id: inserted.insertedId });
    return post;
}
```

I am trying to do a join (reference) between two collections to get the data but I am unable to get required data

```
async getPostsByCategory(categoryId) {
    const posts = this.blogCollection.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: 'categories',
            localField: categoryId,
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'posts_by_categories'
        }
    }])
    return posts;
}
```

posts collection:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "641c4a013e7c5079a9ce8cdd"
  },
  "title": "Test",
  "description": "description",
  "author": "author",
  "categoryId": "641c491e1707a9395caccd00"
}
```

category collection:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "641c491e1707a9395caccd00"
  },
  "categoryName": "misc"
}
```

But I am getting all the blog posts for all categories. Looks like the `lookup` is not correct

I need to get all posts based on categoryId like `posts.categoryId===category._id`

Comment: Please provide some sample documents and the requested output for them

Answer (score 1):

Any command on the aggregation pipeline will work on **all** documents on the current scope. `$lookup` is not different. On your question, you use  `$lookup` as the first step on the pipeline, thus it will work on all the documents in this collection. From your remarks, it seems you are only interested in a specific `categoryId`, which can be seen on the `posts` collection, thus our first step can be `$match`, to leave only the relevant documents (in our case it is only one document). Now we can use `$lookup` to add the data from `categorie` collection to this document. Since the `categoryId` on the `posts` collection is a string, we can use `$lookup` with pipeline to convert the `ObjectId` into string during the pipeline matching:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {$match: {categoryId: categoryId}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      let: {categoryId: "$categoryId"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {$expr: {
              $eq: [{$toString: "$_id"}, "$$categoryId"]
        }}}
      ],
      as: "posts_by_categories"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xNvrfhiy_Ny)

Comment: Actually I don't want to use `categoryImage` because that field is for image url. Updated the question

Comment: I guess I have to replace `"$categoryId"` with actually id right?

Comment: Still I am getting all the records in the output

Comment: Please provide a playground example

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/dy-UGfzmOsy

Comment: I guess you want [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xNvrfhiy_Ny)

Comment: Could you please explain your answer. It will help anyone coming here

Comment: pipeline is inside `lookup`  not required I think. It is working with just `match`

Comment: `const posts = this.blogCollection.aggregate([`
            `{`
   `$lookup: {`
   `from: "categories",`
   `localField: categoryId,`
   `foreignField: '_id',`
   `as: "posts_by_categories"`
  `}`
 `},`
 `{ $match: { categoryId: categoryId } },`
 `{`
  `$project: {`
   `"posts_by_categories": 0`
  `}`
 `}`
`])`